# Displaying a list of object containing a list in a grid view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am currently working on a bookmark manager application (Windows Forms), with advanced search capabilities.

I have created a `Links` class, and every time a user enters a URL, I'll create a Link object and store the details there. It currently has the properties `Name`, `URL` and `Tags`, where `Tags` is a list.

At runtime when I set the `DataSource` property of a gridview to the `List<Links>` objects, the `Name` and the `URL` show up but the *tags do not*.

How do I go about displaying the list of tags inside the `List<Links>` object in the gridview?

**EDIT:** Just had an idea. What if I write a function to convert the `List<Links>` into a `DataTable`, and then set the `DataSource` property of the `DataGrid` to the `DataTable`?

The problem with this is that everytime a change is made to the `List<Links>` I will have to generate the `DataTable` again, which does not seem ideal from a performance point of view.

**EDIT 2:**  I wish to display each item in the list as a DataGridViewTextBox column.

Thanks,

Abijeet.

Comment: Do you have <ItemTemplate> in your GridView, matching the Links class properties? If not, set AutoGenerateColumns=true for the gridview, and the columns should be generated. post your HTML and code behind for binding. Have a look here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1109165.aspx/1

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention, this is a WinForm application.

Comment: in that case, you will need to create a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, and assign the list of tags as the datasource. Then the third column should appear, with a combobox in place. Have a look here: http://arsalantamiz.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/binding-datagridview-combobox-column.html

Comment: @tranceporter, Thanks that link will be helpful in the future, but in this case, I wish to display each item in the list as a `DataGridViewTextBox` column.

Comment: if you have code about the how to create a bookmark. can u send me a complete coding part, I have no idea how to create a bookmark. Thanks In advance...my email id is j.s.banger@hotmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want... an object that appears to have more properties that it actually has.

The `DataGridView` controll supports the `ComponentModel` namespace so that you can create classes that appear to have properties that don't exist. It is the same mechanism the `PropertyGrid` uses.

**Sample code**

This sample is a fully working windows forms class, with a form containing a `DataGridView`. I add some objects to is, using a list that is then set to the `DataSource` property.

The objects inside that list, have no properties at all... but they use component model to describe 'virtual' properties to the `DataGridView`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<MyClass>
                    {
                      new MyClass("value 1", "value 2", "value 3"),
                      new MyClass("value 1", "value 2"),
                    };
        }

        class MyClass : CustomTypeDescriptor
        {
            public MyClass(params string[] tags)
            {
                this.tags = new List<string>(tags);
            }

            public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
            {
                var listProps = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();

                // adding properties dynamically
                for (int i = 0; i < tags.Count; i++)
                    listProps.Add(new PropDesc("Tag" + i, i));

                return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(listProps.ToArray());
            }

            private List<string> tags = new List<string>();

            class PropDesc : PropertyDescriptor
            {
                private int index;

                public PropDesc(string propName, int index)
                    : base(propName, new Attribute[0])
                {
                    this.index = index;
                }

                public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return false; }

                public override Type ComponentType { get { return typeof(MyClass); } }

                public override object GetValue(object component)
                {
                    if (index >= ((MyClass)component).tags.Count)
                        return null;

                    return ((MyClass)component).tags[index];
                }

                public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }

                public override Type PropertyType { get { return typeof(string); } }

                public override void ResetValue(object component) { }

                public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { }

                public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return false; }
            }
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
            ((ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // dataGridView1
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 1;
            // Form1
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in WPF, as I think you do, why not use the DataGridView Row Detail Template? You can have a second grid as the row's detail template which you bind with the tags list.