# Iterating over an array using index and assigning values depending on index

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, design-patterns

<strike>I was facing [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064156/displaying-a-list-of-object-containing-a-list-in-a-grid-view) earlier today, and since I could not find a satisfactory solution, I decided to change my class design, and have seperate properties such as Tag 1, Tag 2, Tag 3 etc.</strike>

My main problem is the fact that I need to bind a grid to an object that contains a list among other properties and I need to show each item in the list as a separate column which I am unable to do. Hence I am resorting to declaring variables separately. [Original question is here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064156/displaying-a-list-of-object-containing-a-list-in-a-grid-view)

Now, I'm facing one of the most common design problem that probably every programmer has at some point of time. Here is the code to demonstrate it,

```
for (int i = 0; i < tags.Length; ++i) // Length not known here.
{
    if(i==0){
        tag1 = tags[0];
    } 
    else if(i == 1){
        tag2 = tags[1];
    }
    else if(i == 2){
        tag3 = tags[2];
    }
    ....
}
```

Here `tags` is a string array.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this. Another thing to note is that the efficiency of this loop decreases as it progresses, since with more iterations it has to check more conditions. If we could remove a condition after it had become *true once* it would speed up each iteration since we know that each condition will become *true only once* in all the iterations

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to assign the elements of `tags` to individual variables?  The whole point of the array is to prevent us from needing individual variables for a contiguous sequence...

Comment: What James said.  Seems like this is walking backwards.

Comment: What is that `tags.Length[]`??? It does not seem valid.

Comment: @James, I am recieving this from the user in a textbox as comma seperated values, I then go on to split the string using string.Split(',') to get that array.

Comment: If you want to assign them to more meaningful variables, that's fine, but you should just do it directly as @MiguelAngelo suggests.

Comment: Because I'm having trouble displaying a list of object [where the object itself contains a list] in a data grid view. I talk about it in the very first line.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064156/displaying-a-list-of-object-containing-a-list-in-a-grid-view

Comment: I was blind about that detail... I understood it now! =)

Comment: Ok then... I have a guess that classes in the ComponentModel namespace will do the job.

Comment: Worst case scenario, I ask the user to enter a maximum of 3-4 tags.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: updated my answer. If you are using a `DataGridView` then I think it is going to work.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: Does the user need to enter data in the grid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moved answer about `DataGridView` and using `ComponentModel` to the correct question:
[Displaying a list of object containing a list in a grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064156/displaying-a-list-of-object-containing-a-list-in-a-grid-view)

**Briefing**

The `DataGridView` controll supports the `ComponentModel` namespace so that you can create classes that appear to have properties that don't exist. It is the same mechanism the `PropertyGrid` uses.

The sample code is in this answer of that question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13078735/195417

**OLD ANSWER**

This was my previous answer, when I didn't realize the real question was about the `DataGridView` control.

---

Isn't this the same as setting the values directly:

```
this.tag1 = tags[0];
this.tag2 = tags[1];
this.tag3 = tags[2];
```

**EDIT**: as you sayd you don't know how many variables will be needed, then you need only one, and that is a list:

```
var list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < tags.Length; ++i)
{
    list.add(tags[i]);
}
```

If all you want is to copy all values, you can even do this:

```
var list = new List<string>(tags);
```

Tell me whether this is what you want or not... maybe I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Ok, sorry! I shouldn't be saying this... maybe the guy is just learning yet.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Thanks for that cheeky comment, really helped to boost my confidence. And no I'm not a beginner. If you would be so kind to answer the updated question, I'd love to get the hell out of here and cry myself to sleep...

Comment: @MiguelAngelo You understood the original question correctly which was wrong, but failed to understand my corrected question. My main problem is the fact that I need to bind a grid to an object that contains a list among other properties and I need to show each item in the list as a separate column. Hence I am resorting to declaring variables separately. I should have explicitly mentioned my requirements, my mistake. Here is the original question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064156/displaying-a-list-of-object-containing-a-list-in-a-grid-view

Comment: I'll change my answer in a minute! I understood it... sorry I was blind for a moment.

Comment: What control is it? A DataGridView?

Comment: This was a pretty stupid question. Atleast I made everyone laugh. Sigh.


I'm going to limit the user to enter a maximum of 4 tags, and use this method to put the value in the 4 tag variables. If the user enters only two tags, I'll initialize the rest of the values to empty string.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo if you could post this answer over in the original question, and unstrike the actual answer here, it would help other people more. Thanks a lot for taking the time out to answer the original question. :)

Answer (score 1):

The whole loop is pointless. But unless the tags array length is always going to be the same, you have to be sure not to go out of bounds...

```
if(tags.Length >= 1) this.tag1 = tags[0];
if(tags.Length >= 2) this.tag2 = tags[1];
if(tags.Length >= 3) this.tag3 = tags[2];
if(tags.Length >= 4) this.tag4 = tags[3];
if(tags.Length >= 5) this.tag5 = tags[4];
```

... so on for however many this.tag# you have.

Comment: This would work somewhat. But still I have no idea how many variables I'll have to declare beforehand.

Comment: ok then, what is 'this' pointing to? At what point is tag1. tag2. tag3 declared (as opposed to assigned to) Are you looking to dynamically create the underlying class so the number of tagX fields changes? or will there be a set # of tagX fields that can be used.

Comment: If you want your underlying class to have tag1, tag2, tag3 properties this time, but tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4 properties next time without modifying your source code, and without recompiling you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2698619/391656 . If however your class always has tag1 through tag9, then you know how many variables you have. you are not changing the number declared, only need to control how many you assign into.

Answer (score -3):

This is essentially the same:

```
for(int index = 0; index < tags.Length[]; index++){
    switch(index){
        case 0:
            tag1 = tags[0];
            break;
            // And so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's no better...  Okay, *marginally* better because it may use a jump-table behind the scenes instead of an if-ladder, but still unnecessary when one can just simply do as @MiguelAngelo suggests, or just *use the array*

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I didn't know if he had to use the loop (for some reason)

Comment: Not to assign the variables, which was the main thrust of his question.  He can still have the loop, but assigning the variables to the contents of each index through the loop is very sub-optimal at best.

Comment: And again for(int index = 0; index < tags.Length[]; index++), it won't compile.