# How do I write a LINQ query whose answer contains a list?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have StudentDB, which is just a list of Student objects, which is defined as:

```
 public class Student
        {
            public String StudentID { get; set; }
            public int ExtraCredit { get; set; }
            public int QtyDemerits { get; set; }
            public List<Demerits> LstDemerits = new List<Demerits>();
        }

  public class Demerits
        {
            public String TeacherID { get; set; }
            public DateTime AsOf { get; set; }
            public String Description1 { get; set; }
            public String Description2 { get; set; }
        }
```

I would like to compile a list of students, ordered by descending order of ExtraCredit, and see all of the student's Demerit details if they have any (i.e. TeacherID, AsOf, Description 1 & 2).

Here's my query, which is not quite yielding everything I want:

```
List<Student> StudentDB2 = new List<Student>();

 StudentDB2 = StudentDB.OrderByDescending(x => x.ExtraCredit).Select(r => new Student
        {
            StudentID = r.StudentID,
            ExtraCredit = r.ExtraCredit,
            QtyDemerits = r.QtyDemerits,
            LstDemerits = r.Demerits.OrderBy(c => c.TeacherID).ThenBy(d => d.AsOf).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = StudentDB2;
```

When I run the code I'm only seeing 3 columns of data: StudentID, ExtraCredit, and QtyDemerits.  But if QtyDemerits > 0, I'm not seeing the data in LstDemerits which should show Teacher Id and As of Date.  What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Is the result what you see in the grid? Or do you have a break point to see what StudenDB2 contains?

Comment: It's the result that is displayed in the datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LstDemerits` property is not being bound to the data source since it is a `List<Demerits`> rather than a string/int, etc.

Try making LstDemerits a string like so:

```
public class Student
{
    public String StudentID { get; set; }
    public int ExtraCredit { get; set; }
    public int QtyDemerits { get; set; }
    public string LstDemerits { get; set; }
}
```

Then write custom logic to properly render a `List<Demerits>` into a string.

```
StudentDB2 = StudentDB.OrderByDescending(x => x.ExtraCredit).Select(r => new Student
        {
            StudentID = r.StudentID,
            ExtraCredit = r.ExtraCredit,
            QtyDemerits = r.QtyDemerits,
            LstDemerits = CustomLogic(r.Demerits)
        })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your query, but rather the `GridView` you're binding your query to. By default, `GridViews` display the properties of the object bound to them, but cannot display complex properties like a `List`. This is reasonable, as attempting to display a `List` as columns leads to hard questions that can't be answered generally. Take your own object as an example: you bind a `List<Student>` to the `GridView`, and suppose the `GridView` then creates four additional columns (one column for each field) for every `Demerits` in each `Student`'s `LstDemerits`. That might work. But what if `Demerits` were assigned by multiple teachers, and so the `TeacherID` field was itself a `List`. Then the `GridView` might add additional columns for each `TeacherID` in this inner object's list. In general, this quickly becomes untenable.

One solution is given as the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064156/displaying-a-list-of-object-containing-a-list-in-a-grid-view). Another solution would be to build a `DataTable` yourself in your code behind so that you can display your objects correctly. Perhaps the easiest solution is to shove your `List<Student>` object into a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, with the `key`s being field names and `value`s being the data from your class, with additional `key`-`value` pairs for each `Demerits` object in the `Student`'s `LstDemerits`. However, this method offers significant disadvantages if you want to do anything with your webpage other than display you information.

In my opinion, this information would be better represented by having a secondary page - the primary page displays each `Student` along with the number of `Demerits` they have, and selecting a `Student` on the primary page takes you to a secondary page that displays all of that `Student`'s `Demerits`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to filter for all those students who has LstDemerits .Count > 0, something like:

```
List<Student> StudentDB2 = new List<Student>();

 StudentDB2 = StudentDB.Where(i => i.LstDemerits.Count > 0).OrderByDescending(x => x.ExtraCredit).Select(r => new Student
        {
            StudentID = r.StudentID,
            ExtraCredit = r.ExtraCredit,
            QtyDemerits = r.QtyDemerits,
            LstDemerits = r.Demerits.OrderBy(c => c.TeacherID).ThenBy(d => d.AsOf).ToList()
        })
        .ToList();

dataGridView1.DataSource = StudentDB2;
```

THis way you should avoid the empty lists, that maybe are your problem at the end. 
I hope this helps

Comment: But I want to see all students whether or not they have demerits.  I don't want to needlessly exclude students whose Demerit count = 0.  Thanks.